# iAd FPS drop (Unity)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, iad, frame-rate

I've made an HD 2D HighScore based game with Unity. After lots of optimization, it works with 60FPS flawlessly. But after I added the iAd banner to my game, the FPS drops to 30 or 40 when the ad is loading or when the ad is animating! Well that hurts! And it's a fast reaction-based game, I don't want any lag with it. I've searched a lot and couldn't find a working solution for my problem. At first I thought Unity's implementation of iAd may have caused the problem(!), so I wrote the native objective-c implementation myself, but the problem remains.

(Tested on iPhone4S, iPhone5s, iPad 3rd Gen, all with iOS 7.1.2)

I would be very glad if anyone could help me :( because it's the only problem preventing me from releasing the game.

Comment: there are many iad oerformance reports recently. I always wonder though how a reaction based game would want to show iads *during gameplay*. The user certainly isn't interested in ads at that point, while many such games place the ads nefariously so that one is prone to click on the suddenly appearing banners.

Comment: Well it's removable via in-app purchase and it's the only monetizing method used in this game. And my game's menu (like pause menu or...) are in game world. (in background there are animations and stuff in scene, entering in play mode only hides the unrelated menus) so if I hide the Ad in the gameplay, I will solve the lag in gameplay, but in pause mode and menus I will still have lags which makes it ugly. I wonder if there is any solution. :-?

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you. I have a 60 fps game and I've been trying out various banner ads. From what I can see, all banner ads impact the perf. I'm using AppLovin now. A lot of the ads work fine, but once in a while there's an animation rich ad that just causes havoc on my frame rate causing it to dip to 30 fps. My plan for monetization is exactly the same. I don't have in game menus as much, but definitely can afford to drop the frame rate in the pause menu and outside the game.

Comment: Didn't found a working solution :/ I hid the ad during the game at last.